Slow down hair simulation
I have an issue with hair simulations and hope somebody here can help me figure it out. I am new to them, and there seems to be much less information about them online than many other Blender features.
I have downloaded a model with a rig and a preset animation. I wish to slow down that animation to various speeds to record it from interesting angles.
When I slow down the characters animation, the speed of the hair simulation does not change. Playing back at 1x speed no matter what I do.
Using the action strip to increase the playback speed changes the character's animation as expected, but the hair animation is completely unaffected. It is always playing back at 1x speed.
Using time interpolation almost gets me there. The hair and character slow down, but the hair moves incredibly choppily. Taking 7 frames to switch to a new 'pose' instead of smoothly moving between frames.
I understand that one solution could be to slow down the animation and simulate all the hair animations again; however, this would ruin the desired look, as the intention is to show a creature running incredibly fast in hyper-slow motion. Resimulating it at a slower speed would make the hair move in a far less dynamic way.
I am curious whether there is a way to convert hair simulations to keyframes, which would allow me to change the animation speed? If anybody has any ideas I'd love to hear them!
I hope this makes sense just through text but can share any useful screenshots or files (via DM) if it would help get to the bottom of this.
Thanks in advance Blender community!
